# Communication between services within the docker compose network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, devops

My question was based on a situation that happened on a daily basis at work. When creating a single dockerfile and using it to create 2 services in docker compose do they communicate the same files and folder?

From this principle it would be, I have service "A" that generated something with the "command" written in docker compose, using as an example an api request that downloads a file "random.txt", and with service "B" I want to be able to take advantage of this file. Using the same dockerfile I am creating a communication between point "A" and "B".

This would be to avoid creating volume in docker compose with same path for both service points "A" and "B". When point "A" something is executed that brings a file to the machine that has its volume connected. To be able to capture in "B" . I have to have another volume.

I will put two example images.

[image: example]

Guys if I'm wrong in any concept, please correct me.

Comment: `do they communicate` It is not possible to answer about the factual state without knowing what it is. Post your dockerfile and docker-compose configuration. What you want or should do, depends solely on you. You can setup a postgres database or NFS server or anything else to store the files, or you can use a volume or a mountpoint. I do not understand what exactly are you asking for - the actual state of some your services or about an implementation design.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Kamilcuk The meaning of this post, if there is the possibility of doing this. With Docker, there's no scripting because I don't know how to express it in lines. Hence my explanation.

Comment: @Ron I know how I should post, not everything will have code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not quite clear, some snippets of code are missing, but I'll make a few assumptions.

Regardless of whether you use the same Dockerfile or not, your only way to share files between containers is to use volumes or bind mounts with the same host path.

Here is an example

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  service-1:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/yourdata
    entrypoint: touch /yourdata/file1

  service-2:
    image: ubuntu
    depends_on:
      - service-1
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/yourdata
    entrypoint: ls /yourdata

volumes:
  datavolume:
```

Here, `service-1` will create a file called `file1` in the volume `datavolume`

`service-2` also mounts that same volume, and thus will be able to access `file1` created by the first service. You can also imagine the `file1` came from an API call instead of being created by the `touch` command.

Here is what it looks like when I ran the above compose file :

[image]

In this case, both services use the same `ubuntu` image (or it can be your own Image created from a Dockerfile. But again, this does not change anything regarding the volumes. The can be 2 completely different images, and still share the same volumes, and files within those volumes.

Cheers